# How to verify a value from a Search list using Slenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have to verify a record from the search list. How can I do it effectively and in a reusable way? I search a keyword that returns 100s of records and then verify my expected search keyword is displayed in the search list.

Here is my code

```
 public void Test_assert_equals() throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            System.out.println("Verify Testcase UploadDocument");
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            driver.findElement(By.name("usernameName")).sendKeys(new CharSequence[]{"dothicamtu@fecredit.com.vn"});
            driver.findElement(By.name("passwordName")).sendKeys(new CharSequence[]{"Abc@123456"});
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-form\"]/mat-spinner-button/button/span[1]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fuseSidebar\"]/navbar/navbar-vertical-style-1/div[2]/div[3]/fuse-navigation/div/fuse-nav-vertical-group[1]/div[2]/fuse-nav-vertical-collapsable[1]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fuseSidebar\"]/navbar/navbar-vertical-style-1/div[2]/div[3]/fuse-navigation/div/fuse-nav-vertical-group[1]/div[2]/fuse-nav-vertical-collapsable[1]/div/fuse-nav-vertical-item/a")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000); //w8 list all data
            //Search
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"isaleleadl2\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/fuse-search-bar/div/div/label/button/span[1]")).click();
            //Search data Vu Manh Hai
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fuse-search-bar-input\"]")).sendKeys(new CharSequence[]{"Vũ Mạnh Hải"});
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fuse-search-bar-input\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            //String result= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"isaleleadl2\"]/div[2]")).getText();
            //Assert.assertEquals("Vũ Mạnh Hải", result);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMjtE.png)

I have using this logic check but got an errors in "assertEquals"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YEBk.png)
i need to verify "Vũ Mạnh Hải" is displayed in the search list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d0sg.png)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reference to the expected number of results containing the 'keyword', but if I know that there should be at least 1 result; then I would do the following:

Instead of using findElement I would get a list of elements by using findElements and check whether the size of the list is larger than 0.

It would look similar to the following:

```
List<WebElement> result = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@col-
id='issueName'][contains(text(),’Vu Manh Hai’)]"));

Assert.assertTrue(result.size()>0);
```

Of course this is based on assumption that the keyword results in at least 1 search result. If you could get the number of the search results from a database query or so that would be much more accurate.